# To what granularity are expressions in function call parameters interleaved?

Tags: c++, specifications, copy-on-write

I would like to fully understand what is exactly specified about how function call parameters are interleaved. It seems to me to have many implications. Take the following example:

```
void mad(cow_string a, cow_string b);
cow_string s("moo");
cow_string s1 = s;
cow_string s2 = s;
mad(s1+="haha",s2+="hahaha");
```

where `cow_string` is a Copy-On-Write string container like Sutter describes on GotW here: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/045.htm

1. If the evaluation of `s1+="haha"` and `s2+="hahaha"` are interleaved to a very fine granularity wouldn't that mean that this is creating a race condition on cow_strings internal ref count (depending on the compiler)?
2. If I try to protect against the race condition with a mutex couldn't that even cause a self lock in a single threaded program (which makes my head hurt). E.g. S1 makes an internal copy and acquires the mutex to decrease the ref count ***context switches*** S2 also makes an internal copy and runs to the mutex and bam self lock.
3. (only if the first are true) Is there safe way to make an object a COW if the rest of my team are not gurus or don't know its a COW?

Edit:

For clarity my picture of the expressions not being very interleaved was shaken by Herb Sutters example of this:

```
// In some header file:
void f( T1*, T2* );

// In some implementation file:
f( new T1, new T2 );
```

doing this:

```
allocate memory for the T1
construct the T1
allocate memory for the T2
construct the T2
call f()
```

or this:

```
allocate memory for the T1
allocate memory for the T2
construct the T1
construct the T2
call f()
```

read about it here: http://flylib.com/books/en/3.259.1.55/1/

Second Edit:
I guess I was assuming an reference counter changing function in `cow_string` to be inlined, which is a stupid assumption. Without that stupid assumption my question doesn't really make much sense. Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: re your edit about new operator - yes, Sutter is right.  We have another ABCD pattern analogous to what I wrote in my answer.  The new for T1 or T2 can be called in any order, and calling the constructor on that space can be called in either order but only after the space for that entity is called. So C must follow A, and D must follow B, but otherwise the compiler can do as it pleases.

Comment: And to clarify: the new doesn't do anything to the memory it allocates.  That is in unknown state (garbage) when new completes.  Only after the constructors are called will that space begin to "mean" anything, hold anything meaningful.  The problem here is a classic one of resource leakage, and a primary motivator for using smart pointers.  Somewhere Sutter or Meyers or both has a rule of thumb to never have an expression with multiple new's in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question changed to:

```
void mad(cow_string & a, cow_string & b);
cow_string s("moo");
cow_string s1 = s;
cow_string s2 = s;
mad(s1+="haha",s2+="hahaha");
```

You've got a question that maybe makes a little more sense.  Here the interactions between `s1 +=` and `s2 +=` could potentially interfere if the compiler somehow interleaved their execution (presumably by throwing in extra threads).

However, no, it can't.  C++ compilers don't throw in extra threads, and they don't 1/2 execute a method and switch to executing another.  `s1`'s `cow_string::operator+=` or `s2`'s `cow_string::operator+=` will execute to completion, and only then will the other begin, and only after both complete will `mad` be called.

The order of execution of the subexpressions in the call to `mad` are left to the compiler implementation - but they can't interleave somehow in a single thread and standard compilers can't throw in extra threads.

Herb Sutter is trying to get across the point that the subexpressions don't need to happen in left-to-right order, or in depth first order.  Rather, that they can happen in any order (including interleaved) within the rules-framework of function calls themselves!

That last piece is critical.  It cannot violate basic call mechanics, or order of evaluation of a complete argument-passing period.

So, if we decide the above expression has 4 mini-operations:

A) `"haha"` is converted to a temporary `cow_string` that will be handed to `cow_string::operator+=`
B) The same thing for `"hahaha"`
C) the temp from A will be handed to `S1::+=`
D) the temp from B will be handed to `S2::+=`

There are not infinite ways that this can go down, rather:

A, B, C, D
A, B, D, C
A, C, B, D
B, D, A, C
B, A, C, D
B, A, D, C

That's it.  A function call such as `cow_string(const char*)` is not interleavable.  Nor is operator `+=`.  Those are function calls.  Their arguments must be fully evaluated before they can be called.  The call must complete fully before any further evaluation in the outer context may resume.

Here's an example where things are in fact ambiguous:

```
int a = 5;
foo(a+=9*4, a+=13/2);
```

The compiler can choose in what order to evaluate the arguments (and the subexpressions in the arguments) to foo in any order it so pleases.  So what a ends up with when `foo()` receives it is anyone's guess (and will vary from compiler to compiler).

---

As to your edit example of two calls to new as arguments to a function.

```
foo(new T1, new T2);
```

because either or both `new`s can be called before either constructor, and because they can throw, you have the potential for a memory leak.

If the compiler generates:

```
new T1  
new T2  
T1()  
T2()
```

And if `new T2` throws, then the memory for `T1` is lost.  There is no owner of the space of `T1` that will deallocate it.

Even if the compiler does call `new T1`, `T1()`, `new T2` throw's, you can have a memory leak here because nobody owns the space that `T1` occupies - and you can have additional problems because `T1`'s constructor ran, but is now abandoned.  So any side-effects it generated will not be undone / managed / cleaned up / etc.

Keep reading Herb Sutter.  His Exceptional C++ and More Exceptional C++ are excellent, and go into these issues in great depth!

Comment: in Sutters book More Exceptional C++ Item 20 he seems to suggest a finer granularity. here is the chapter as an e-book http://flylib.com/books/en/3.259.1.55/1/

Comment: my idea is that if the two constructors in his example can be split into allocate and construct and interleaved in different orders then how far can that go?

Comment: see more in my answer (won't fit here)

Comment: so the interleaving Sutter is talking about is a special case for new and nothing else?

Comment: Allocation at the level of the compiler reserving stack space to hold the temp of cow_string("haha") and temp cow_string("hahaha") doesn't call a constructor on that space.  There is no internal count in that space.  That space is NOT a cow_string - just the space where one will be.  The call of the constructor for the cow_string in-place on the stack or wherever those temps are allocated are themselves restricted by the call rules, and cannot be interleaved.

Comment: new is not being invoked in your or my examples.  new has some gotchas to pay attention to, but it is restricted to the same rules as the rest of the system.  what exactly would be your question about new?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is.  There are no writes of any strings
in the call to `mad`, so copy on write doesn't come into play.  The only
copies are from the temporary results of the `+` operator and the value
parameters of `mad` (and these can be elided).

With regards to threading, threading problems are one of the reasons
copy on write has lost favor: it's still used by g++, but there is an
error in its thread handling (which can only be triggered in some very
exceptional circumstances).  Generally speaking, it's not hard to make a
thread-safe copy on write, and it's not hard to make an efficient copy
on write, but it's almost impossible to combine the two.  (At least for
the interface of `std::basic_string<>`.  With a more rational interface,
it wouldn't be that difficult.)

The key issues in a thread-safe copy-on-write are making the updates of
the use count atomic, and if the string exposes its implementation to
modification from outside (as does `std::basic_string`), ensuring that
the decision to isolate the implemenation (ensuring a use count of 1,
always, so that the modifications from the outside don't affect other
instances) is atomic with the marking that the string is isolated.
(This last point is where the g++ implementation fails: if you try to
copy the string in one thread, and access it via `operator[]` in
another, and the initial use count is 1, you may end up with two
instances sharing a copy of the implementation which is marked as
isolated—the comments in the C++ source code call this
&ldqou;orphaned”.)

At any rate, given the code you show: using a copy-on-write
implementation of `cow_string`, `s`, `s1` and `s2` would share an
implementation, with a use count of 3.  The expressions `s1 + "haha"`
and `s2 + "hahaha"` would each create a new, temporary string (with a
use count of 1, initially).  But I'm not sure what your problem is: your code never modifies any of the strings, so the only problem is ensuring that the update of the use count is atomic.

Comment: i changed the s1 + "haha" to s1 += "haha" to avoid this misunderstanding. sorry for being unclear.

Comment: wouldn't my origional idea have work though, because s1 + "haha" would first result in a temporary with an internal pointer to the contents origionally created in s and then when adding "haha" it would make a real copy and decrease the ref count?

Comment: It's still not clear what kind of problem you're worried about.  The management of the use count is within the string class, with function calls for each elementary operator.  Both the call and the return are sequence points, and the compiler is not allowed to interleaf function calls; if you're not concerned about performance, just acquire a mutex lock on entering each function, and free it on leaving, and you should have no problems.  (Except performance.)

Comment: If the problem exists a mutex won't solve it as I mentioned in my question above.

Comment: I haven't really figured out your question yet.  The results of `s1 + "haha"` would be a temporary, with no reference what so ever to `s1`, at least with the usual implementations.  But even with an implementation along the lines of `rope`, if the update of the reference count is atomic, there should be no problems.

Comment: Regarding the problem you mention in your edit: I'm familiar with it (since I'm the one who first pointed it out).  But it's not relevant here: each of the operations on your string is in a separate function, and the compiler is **not** allowed to interleaf functions; there is a sequence point on entering into and on returning from a function.

Comment: In a GC system, could one make an efficient copy-on-write if each wrapper holds a reference to both a mutable and immutable instance (either *one* of which could be null)?  Making a logical copy of an wrapper would copy the immutable from the mutable one if not null, and generate a new wrapper with the immutable instance copied from the first and the mutable one blank.  Mutating a wrapper would generate a new mutable object from an immutable one if it doesn't exist yet (CompareExchange the ref) and invalidate the immutable copy.  No need for reference counts or any such things.

Comment: Such an approach would generate some redundant instances (e.g. if an object is copied exactly once and that copy is mutated, the immutable reference would be a waste) though that could be eased with a "CopyAsNewMutable" method.